# Is there a way to export starred items from Google Reader?

Tags: google-reader

I am familiar with exporting/importing RSS feeds, however I would like some way to backup the thousands of starred items that I have collected in Google Reader.

I don't even necessarily need to be able to export the "blurb" contained with the starred item (although that would be nice), as long as I am able to pull the URL.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 13):

1. Go to Google Reader.
2. Go to the `Settings` page.
3. Click on `Folders and Tags`.
4. Your starred items are private, you can make them public.
5. then you can access a public page which has a feed.
6. Look at the XML, almost all XML from Google Reader has something that looks like this:

   <gr:continuation>CJyPg4L2wKIC</gr:continuation>
7. take that and add it to the end of the RSS URL like so ?c=CJyPg4L2wKIC, it will allow you to paginate through your starred articles.

Answer (score 7):

You need to go to Google Takeout (https://www.google.com/takeout) and select Google Reader and do an export.

The zipped file you download contains a fairly comprehensive export of your Google Reader settings:

- followers.json
- following.json
- liked.json
- notes.json
- shared-by-followers.json
- shared.json
- **starred.json**
- subscriptions.xml (an OPML file)

Answer (score 3):

Google Reader now also supports extra export options. If you go to Reader Settings and then the Import/Export tab, you'll see links that let you download items you've starred in a couple JSON-based formats.

They aren't terribly readable by themselves, although you can figure out where links are with a simple text editor, but if you have another RSS program that's able to read it, you should be able to view the exports that way.

Answer (score 1):

Go to this link:

http://www.google.com/reader/atom/user/-/state/com.google/starred?n=5000

This produces an XML file that contains all of your starred items.  There is no need to make your items public to do this.  There is no need for pagination or continuation tricks.  The XML file contains the complete content for each item; not just a link.

See that "5000" at the end of the link there?  That controls the maximum number of items the XML file will show.  Bump it up if you need to.

Note: If you have an RSS reader extension installed in your browser, it may attempt to parse the XML file into an RSS feed for you.  In my case, the "RSS Subscription Extension" for Chrome was "helping" by truncating the number of items.  Turning the extension off allowed me to see (and save) the complete, raw XML file.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it http://www.rimmkaufman.com/rkgblog/2008/09/19/google-reader-export-starred-posts/ it does look to be a bit ugly and not straightforward though.

Answer (score 0):

This MIGHT work for you...

Load your STARRED items in Google Reader. Copy the URL, like so:

> *https://www.google.com/reader/**view/#stream**/user%2F14791004...804797%2Fstate%2Fcom.google%2Fstarred*

Change the bolded portion to read **atom**, like so:

*https://www.google.com/reader/**atom**/user%2F1479100...804797%2Fstate%2Fcom.google%2Fstarred*

Load that up and see if it works out.

***NOTE: That link won't work for anyone and this solution will only work if you have an active login session with Google Reader.***

Answer (score 0):

I share while starring them. Then I use the RSS feed to import the feeds into an external RSS reader like Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

I made a ruby script that exports the link of each starred items to a txt file and an html file (to import as bookmarks).

[You can get it here](http://github.com/phmongeau/Supernova)

Answer (score 0):

> http://www.google.com/reader/atom/user/-/state/com.google/starred?n=5000
>
> See that "5000" at the end of the link there? That controls the
>   maximum number of items the XML file will show. Bump it up if you need
>   to.

that worked only for the first 1000 items for me. i did not find a way to go beyond the 1000, the resulting xml doesn't change, no matter what the 'n=' number is..

Comment: welcome to the web applications stack exchange site. I can't see how your answer has added anything different to other answers that have already posted. Unless you can edit it in such a way that it does, I would suggest that you post your answer as a comment instead.